# Union Select Column Mismatch

Tags: mysql, select, union

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added,  '%m-%d-%Y' ) AS formatted_date,
    SUM( tb =1 ) AS sum_users,
    SUM( tb =2 ) AS sum_links,
    SUM( tb =3 ) AS sum_ads,
    SUM( tb =4 ) AS sum_actions
FROM (
    SELECT date_added, 1 AS tb
        FROM users_list WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_added, 2
        FROM users_links WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_served, 3
        FROM ads_served WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_served, 4
        FROM actions WHERE 1=1
) AS t
GROUP BY formatted_date
ORDER BY formatted_date DESC
```

Here's my table data:

users_list

```
id    date_added
1     1234567890
2     1334567890
3     1434567890
```

users_links

```
id    date_added
1     1244567890
2     1354567890
3     1464567890
```

ads_served

```
id    date_served    revenue
1     1234567891     0.01
2     1334567892     0.02
3     1434567893     0.02
```

actions

```
id    date_served
1     1234561890
2     1334562890
3     1434563890
```

I am trying to sum the revenue for formatted_date in the ads_served table as a 6th column for the output query. I am lost as to where to start. If I add the sum(revenue) to the union select I get a "column mismatch" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way. Why do you use 1=1 ?

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added,  '%m-%d-%Y' ) AS formatted_date,
    SUM( tb =1 ) AS sum_users,
    SUM( tb =2 ) AS sum_links,
    SUM( tb =3 ) AS sum_ads,
    SUM( tb =4 ) AS sum_actions,
    sum(total) as tot_rev
FROM (
    SELECT date_added,'' as total, 1 AS tb
        FROM users_list WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_added,'', 2
        FROM users_links WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_served,revenue, 3
        FROM ads_served WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_served,'', 4
        FROM actions WHERE 1=1
) AS t
GROUP BY formatted_date
ORDER BY formatted_date DESC
```

Comment: there should be a comma after "as total" btw

Comment: I forgot to edit out WHERE 1=1 for the sake of this example. In code, there are filters applied to each SELECT statement. I use the "1=1" to ensure that the following filter will have " and" in front to make applying the filters easier.

Comment: Ok, I supposed you were creating dynamic query.

Comment: Ah, ok. I had already fixed it as son as I posted my message. I was afraid I had forgotten something else. :)

Comment: @user396449: manji did the same thing but his solution of using 0 instead of an empty string is more correct. :) Apply it to your final query.

Answer (score 3):

Column `revenue` belongs to `ads_served` but you are selecting from a sub query where `revenue` is not present. Add it to the subquery:

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME( date_added,  '%m-%d-%Y' ) AS formatted_date,
    SUM( tb =1 ) AS sum_users,
    SUM( tb =2 ) AS sum_links,
    SUM( tb =3 ) AS sum_ads,
    SUM( tb =4 ) AS sum_actions,
    SUM( revenue ) As sum_revenue
FROM (
    SELECT date_added, 1 AS tb, 0 As revenue
        FROM users_list WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_added, 2, 0
        FROM users_links WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_served, 3, revenue
        FROM ads_served WHERE 1=1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT date_served, 4, 0
        FROM actions WHERE 1=1
) AS t
GROUP BY formatted_date
ORDER BY formatted_date DESC
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. you were 2 minutes to late sadly. upvoted for your help.